Error while creating the subnets using Terraform
I created a variable.tf file and adding the below VPC and Subnet codes.
variable "VPC_ID" {
  description = "This is VPC created using variables and not as hard coded information."
  type        = string
  default     = "My-VPC"
}

variable "cidr" {
  description = "Setting up with the IPv4 CIDR blocks which can be used for this testing project."
  type        = string
  default     = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "Public_Subnet" {
  description = "Creating an Ip4 Public Subnet."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

variable "Public_AVZ" {
  description = "This needs to be used for public availability zone only."
  type        = string
  default     = "aps1-az1"
}

I then created 2 seperate .tf files for VPC and Subnet and added the below codes into it.
resource "aws_vpc" "My-VPC" {
  cidr_block       = var.cidr
  instance_tenancy = var.Instance_tenancy

  tags = {
    Name = var.VPC_ID
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "Public_Subnet" {
  vpc_id     = var.VPC_ID
  cidr_block = var.cidr
}

Now when I run the validate and plan commands, it does not show any error and shows all correct. However, when I run the apply command, I get the below error.

Error: creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidVpcID.NotFound: The vpc ID 'My_VPC' does not exist
│       status code: 400, request id: 5d6d19ed-2067-4653-8611-c6fdc48b24f4
│
│   with aws_subnet.Public_Subnet,
│   on subnets.tf line 3, in resource "aws_subnet" "Public_Subnet":
│    3: resource "aws_subnet" "Public_Subnet" {
│

Tried few blogs and tweaked the setting, but with no luck.

The name you are assigning the VPC is not the VPC's ID, it is just a name. You should probably rename the variable to something like VPC_NAME.
The VPC's ID is an ID that AWS assigns to your VPC at the time it is created. It is available in Terraform as an attribute of the VPC resource.
Your subnets needs to reference the ID attribute of the VPC resource, like this:
resource "aws_vpc" "My-VPC" {
  cidr_block       = var.cidr
  instance_tenancy = var.Instance_tenancy
}


resource "aws_subnet" "Public_Subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.My-VPC.id
  cidr_block = var.cidr
}


Thanks Mark, all sorted now. I tried using "vpc_id     = aws_vpc.My-VPC.id", but forgot to apply that .id at the end, so even  that was throwing an error.
Thanks for a quick solution and a help. Cheers.

@SupportTestemailaccount please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.

VPC ID is not something you define the value for. It is provided after the VPC resource is created. The VPC ID is in the following format:
vpc-01abcdefff3456789

You can find it in the AWS console:

Since you are using terraform, you can use the implicit reference:
resource "aws_vpc" "My-VPC" {
  cidr_block       = var.cidr
  instance_tenancy = var.Instance_tenancy

  tags = {
    Name = var.VPC_ID
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "Public_Subnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.MY_VPC.id
  cidr_block = var.cidr
}


The VPC is being created in the Terraform code. You would need to use the VPC resource attribute to reference the ID, not a data source.

Thanks Marko, all sorted now. I tried using "vpc_id     = aws_vpc.My-VPC.id", but forgot to apply that .id at the end, so even  that was throwing an error.
Thanks for a quick solution and a help. Cheers.
